# is it possible to create an ios/android app which limits a user from using an app or website for a certain period of time

Tags: android, ios

Lately I've been wondering if I could create an app which disables the user's ability to use certain apps for a period of time until either the time is up or they are give a string of characters to enter (in order to re-enable the disabled apps).

I'm asking this since I don't know if ios allows such things to happen on their platform. I believe android allows their developers to do this, but I need confirmation.

Thanks :-)

Comment: not possible in iOS

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to develop an app that does this on iOS.

However, it’s an idea that Apple themselves have already implemented in iOS 12 (which is due for release soon).

It’s called Screen Time, and it helps the user to track the amount of time they spend in apps, limit the amount of time they’re allowed to use them, and limit their children’s use of apps too:

https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/06/ios-12-introduces-new-features-to-reduce-interruptions-and-manage-screen-time/

So it’s not really a viable idea for an app on iOS anyway, since the OS itself will offer these features very soon.